Multiline parser for python log format using fluent-bit. getting single line log entry on elastic while i want it to be a single block
sample log entry -
2024-06-14 06:51:58.906 | INFO     | __main__:main:30 - All indicators and predictions:
[
    {
        "datetime":1718308800000,
        "key1":66701.7292561551,
        "key2":67014.6836462447,
        "key3":66529.3890236763,
        "key4":66880.5703857987,
        "key5":1132.28416,
        "key6":744.0276710022,
        "key7":0,
        "key8":0.0585026458,
        "key9":0,
        "key10":"",
        "key11":null
    }
]
2024-06-14 06:51:58.907 | INFO     | __main__:main:31 -                datetime          key1          key2           key3         key4      key5  ...        key6  key7  key8  key9  key10  key11
994 2024-06-13 20:00:00  66701.729256  67014.683646  66529.389024  66880.570386  1132.28416  ...  744.027671       0    0.058503        0                 NaN
995 2024-06-13 22:00:00  66880.569752  66991.561215  66630.729675  66808.863462   788.89703  ...  680.327224       0    0.036088        0                 NaN
996 2024-06-14 00:00:00  66808.863251  66929.160405  66530.243225  66807.067821  1427.33212  ...  660.197075       0   -0.004118        0                 NaN
997 2024-06-14 02:00:00  66807.067750  66994.600135  66627.601075  66765.022607  1277.60587  ...  648.589025       0    0.036305        0                 NaN
998 2024-06-14 04:00:00  66765.022583  67145.746712  66681.040358  66956.667536  1253.85572  ...  640.019675       0    0.151628        0                 NaN

[5 rows x 24 columns]
2024-06-14 06:51:58.935 | INFO     | __main__:main:66 - No new signals found
2024-06-14 06:51:58.935 | INFO     | __main__:main:68 - Time taken: 0.6224438566714525

I am unable to parse them properly.
Trying to format them in order -
timestamp | level | message
my fluent-bit conf file -
[SERVICE]
    Flush        1
    Log_Level    info
    Parsers_File multiline_parsers.conf
    Daemon       Off
    HTTP_Server  On
    HTTP_Listen  0.0.0.0
    HTTP_Port    2020
    Health_Check On

[FILTER]
   Name               parser
   Match              jarvis.*
   Key_Name           log
   Parser             jarvis_parser

[INPUT]
    Name                tail
    Path                /path/to/log/log-file.log
    Parser              multiline-log
    Tag                 jarvis.archi
    Read_From_Head      true
    Buffer_Chunk_Size  1M
    Buffer_Max_Size    5M

[OUTPUT]
    Name                es
    Match               jarvis.archi
    Host                IP
    Port                PORT
    HTTP_User           USER
    HTTP_Passwd         PASSWD
    Retry_Limit         False
    Suppress_Type_Name  On
    Logstash_Format     On
    Logstash_Prefix     index-name-

multiline_parsers.conf - 
[MULTILINE_PARSER]
    Name          multiline-log
    Type          regex
    Flush_Timeout 1000
    Rule          "start_state"    "/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3} \| [A-Z]+     \| .*/" "cont"
    Rule          "cont"           "/^\s+/"                                "cont"

Using it to parse python logs.
Tried multiple
regexp -
^(?<timestamp>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}) \| (?<level>[A-Z]+) \| (?<module>[^:]+):(?<function>[^:]+):(?<line>\d+) - (?<message>.*)

I also tried using a lua script to extract the log message but that too didn’t work.
What all changes should i make i am getting logs in different lines only.

this appears to be complex (partially structured) data. it would be best to read the file properly and parse it. i doubt that a single regex will suffice...

When i 'cat' the log file i get this output only. I read json data mostly as it has complete info. The ... between key5 and key6 actually has complete data in the json part of message.
I also feel like changing the parser and regex but i still it should at least generate the log from timestamp to timestamp, irrespective of the data type in message field.
And its the sample log provided above that is being repeated every time.

in that respect, make a minimal reproducible example

how to ask a good question:
how to ask
